# jQuery methods not working on 'this' inside an event handler

Tags: jquery, html

When I use the below, I cannot get the jQuery `this` to hide the element.

```
$('.purplePanda').click(function(e){
   this.hide();
});
```

I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: this.hide is not a function`

Comment: `this` isn't a jQuery object so you can't use jQuery methods on it...`$(this)` converts it

Comment: `.purplePanda` is a div

Comment: Wait, is @StackOverflow trying to answer some simple questions that are common errors of early devs?

Answer (score 6):

Replace

```
this.hide();
```

with

```
$(this).hide();
```

Thus your function should be like

```
$('.purplePanda').click(function(e){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

See the official documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: Your period is in the wrong place in the full code example @lal

Answer (score 2):

**Modify your code from that :**

```
$('.purplePanda').click(function(e){
   this.hide();
});
```

**To This:**

```
$('.purplePanda').click(function(e){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Should work now.